# Bias tee for floating DC supply

Tags: capacitor, rf, dc, inductor, floating

I have a floating DC low noise current source driving a load.  I also need to drive this load with an RF source but the grounds are not referenced to each other so I don't think I can use a standard bias tee. I have thought of a quick solution to this by modifying the bias tee slightly as shown below. Resistance of the load is ~0.1 Ohm and inductance ~1uH. Is this a reasonable solution?

R1 is the load, 12V and 0V connectors indicate the current source output.

[image]

Comment: What's the load? That can make a big difference to whether it will behave when not connected to ground.

Comment: @ThePhoton The load is a small coil consisting of 8 turns with a 3mm radius. Also the rf will be around 2MHz.

Comment: Okay, a simple passive should have no trouble with being floated like that.